# phonegap --autoreload and console.log not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, refresh, console.log, phonegap-cli

I am building a phonegap app and need quick test feedback on the live devices

- Smasung Galaxy note 3
- iPhone 5s

I am using phonegap CLI to serve.

I have been building on my home desktop PC running windows 7, and am currently working elsewhere on my laptop running windows 10. Now I have run into the following problem:

**On my desktop PC:**

After each change on either the javascript or HTML file, the phonegap server **autoreloads** the app and the changes show almost immediately on the devices.
I also get the **console.log** replies in the CLI.

**On my laptop:**

After each change on either the javascript or the HTML file I get a message on the CLI that the relevant file has been changed (this does not happen on my desktop PC) and there is no autoreloading of the apps on the test devices neither does it give a readout of the console.log replies and any alert() that I use in their place take much longer to pop up than normal...

- I have set --autoreload when starting the phonegap server (although it's default is 'true' anyway).
- I have reinstalled phonegap.
- I have run everything off a whole other network.
- I have waited very patiently incase it's just slow network.
- I have gotten to the point where I want to punch a baby in the face.

Is there anyone who can shed some light on how I can get the **autoreload** and the **console.log** working ???

Regards

Answer (score 4):

So after some tedious debugging I found it.

in the head section I added:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

although I already had:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

and it's still like that on my desktop PC...

and now everything works...both the console.log and the autoreloading...

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Here's a bit more clarification for you: I ran into this issue with a new project now, even though I also had the `cordova.js` script reference *without* the `type` attribute. After adding `type="text/javascript"`, then I see references to `socket.io` in the console after starting `phonegap serve` and the app auto-reloads on changes as expected.